# Debug messages not getting logged in 'Error Log' in Marklogic-9

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

Debug messages not getting logged in 'Error Log' in MarkLogic 9.0-9.1, even after setting the **file log level** to `finest` (which is the least log level).

From QConsole, used `xdmp:log('xyz', 'debug')` after setting the **file log level** 
to 'finest' (tried with other log levels also) in the group config from admin UI, but debug messages are not getting logged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now since ** I Marklogic-9 each application server writes to its own xxxx_ErrorLog.txt, where xxxx is the port number** (e.g. logs from `qconsole` will be captured in `8000_ErrorLog.txt`- if it is the port on which `qconsole` is running), **there is an option to select the minimum log level - `file log level` in each `App Server`'s 
 admin configuration panel** (Group->{Group_name}->App Servers->{your_app_server_name}->Configure->`file log level`).

The `Group`-`file log level` (Group->{Group_name}->Configure->`file log level`) configuration now works for the general `ErrorLog.txt`.

Answer (score 5):

Check that you're looking in the right log file. As of MarkLogic 9, each application server writes to its own xxxx_ErrorLog.txt, where xxxx is the port number. Query Console runs on port 8000, so you'd look in 8000_ErrorLog.txt. Prior to MarkLogic 9, all error messages went to ErrorLog.txt.

Comment: Thanks for replying @Dave Cassel, I am looking in the right log file i.e. **8000_ErrorLog.txt** (since I am running the code from `QConsole`). I am able to see the `INFO` logs in the **8000_ErrorLog.txt**.

Comment: I just tested this in MarkLogic 9.0-9.1 and I see the same thing. Looks like a bug. @Ashish Patil, if you have a Support contract, please let them know (if not, please say so and we can alert them in other ways).

Comment: Thanks @Dave, I do not have a support contract; so, is there any other way to alert the `Marklogic` team.

Comment: You can write to community-requests@marklogic.com and ask them to file a bug on behalf of the community. I don't know whether you'll get notified when it gets fixed, but they'll want to know about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dave Cassel. Appreciate your quick support.

Comment: Dave Cassel, there is an option to select the minimum log level - `file log level` in each `App Server`'s admin configuration panel.